# Remove user from google-sudoers in google cloud platform linux box

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am using `google cloud` and I know this question is already asked. I am using `ubuntu 18.04 LTS` I created the user key using `puttygen` and add its public key content to the metadata project level in `google cloud platform`

```
user: saw1005
```

now this user is a part of `google-sudoers` but I want to remove this user from this group.

I use this command:

```
sudo deluser saw1005 google-sudoers
```

this command also work but when I restart the server it also get added.

I also tried to add this command in the crontab but didn't work.

So all I want is to remove the user from the google-sudoers so he/she cannot use `sudo` command.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As a possible solution you can start using OS Login. Have a look at the documentation [Setting up OS Login](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access):

> OS Login lets you use [Compute Engine IAM roles](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam) to grant or revoke
> SSH access to your Linux instances. OS Login is an alternative to
> managing instance access by [adding and removing SSH keys in
> metadata](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys).

and at the section [Step 4: Configuring OS Login roles on user accounts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access#configure_users):

> To allow OS Login access to these VMs, you need to grant the necessary
> roles to the user. To allow OS Login access, complete the following
> steps:
>
> Grant one of the following instance access roles.
>
> - `roles/compute.osLogin`, **which does not grant administrator permissions**
> - `roles/compute.osAdminLogin`, which grants administrator permissions.
>
> **Note**: *If the user has the primitive `roles/owner` or `roles/admin` role,
> or if they have `roles/compute.instanceAdmin`, these roles already
> include instance access roles with administrator permissions*.

also, at the section [Step 5: (Optional) Adding SSH keys to a user account](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access#add_oslogin_keys):

> **Note**: *This step is optional. If you do not add SSH keys, Compute Engine automatically generate these keys for you when you connect to
> instances.*
>
> If you want connect to your VMs by using third party tools, you need
> to add your SSH keys to your user account. If you connect to your
> instances using other options such as gcloud command-line tool or SSH
> from the browser, you can skip this step as Compute Engine
> automatically generate these keys for you.

Let's try to create privileged and unprivileged users:

1. create VM instance:

   ```
   gcloud compute instances create instance-1 --zone=europe-west3-a --machine- type=e2-medium --image=ubuntu-1804-bionic-v20200626 --image-project=ubuntu-os-cloud
   ```
2. enable OS Login (for VM instance only in this case):

   ```
   gcloud compute instances add-metadata instance-1 --metadata enable-oslogin=TRUE --zone=europe-west3-a
   ```
3. create users and grant `roles/compute.osAdminLogin` and `roles/compute.osLogin` roles.
4. connect with privileged account (role `roles/compute.osAdminLogin` was grunted):

   ```
   $ gcloud compute ssh privileged@instance-1 --zone=europe-west3-a 
   ...
   privileged_domain_com@instance-1:~$ sudo -s
   root@instance-1:~#
   ```
5. connect with unprivileged account (role `roles/compute.osLogin` was grunted):

   ```
   $ gcloud compute ssh unprivileged@instance-1 --zone=europe-west3-a 
   ...
   unprivileged_domain_com@instance-1:~$ sudo -s
   ...
   unprivileged_domain_com is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported.
   ```

Everything works as expected and only privileged user was added to `google-sudoers`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `startup-script` in your VM's custom metadata to add, modify or remove users.
For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo deluser USERNAME google-sudoers
```

[image]